# Involutions in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$

Tags: reference-request, formal-power-series

Question: For a prime $p$, is every involution in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ a reduction modulo $p$ of some involution in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$?

Obviously, a reduction mod $p$ of an involution in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$ yields an involution in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$, but do we get all involutions in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ this way?

Also, if you know of a reference where this is discussed, please let me know. Thank you.

*Update:* As noted by @quasi, $1+x$ is an involution modulo $2$, but it's not a reduction of any involution $f\in\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, since $f(0)=0$ for any such $f$. So, a modified version of this question is: are all involutions in $\mathbb{F}_p[[x]]$ *with a zero constant term* reductions mod $p$ of involutions in $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$?

Comment: What do you mean by involution? Is a a power series with $f(f(x))=x$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Yes, a compositional self-inverse.

Comment: If $p=2$, the function $f(x)=1+x$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @quasi OK, thanks for that one, I knew there had to be an easy counterexample. What if one considers only power series with a 0 constant term?

Comment: For answers to this question, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/330811/involutions-in-mathbbf-px